# How do you install Qt 4.7.3 in Windows?

Tags: qt

Not just that. Please specify what Environment variables should I add, and other things to configure for desktop development. -Perroquiet (Qt newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the docs? They are very easily found via google search: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/install-win.html

In the docs they specify environment variables and take you through all the other steps necessary.

Is the a particular point of the install you're having troubles with, or have you just not read the docs yet?